# Javascript file isn't loading on local host

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

> I am just learning express and I tried to create a simple webpage on localhost:3000. I created a text box with a submit button, which on click will get the text element inside the text box and print it on the console.

My node.js code is:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')

const app=express();

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
const dir= path.join(__dirname,'../templates/views');
const partials=path.join(__dirname,'../templates/partials')
app.set('views',dir);
hbs.registerPartials(partials);

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('test')
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port`);
});
```

The test.hbs file code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     {{>header}}
    <form class="form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Write here" class="textbox">
        <input type="submit" class="btn">
    </form>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript code is

```
const values={
    nodeForm:document.querySelector('.form'),
    nodeText:document.querySelector('.textbox'),
    nodeBtn:document.querySelector('.btn')
}

values.nodeForm.addEventListener('submit',e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(nodeText.value)
    
})
```

But when I open up the `localhost:3000`, the console page gives me an error, saying `GET http://localhost:3000/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Edit: Javascript works fine if I put scripts inside the script tag present in the test.hbs file

Comment: `querySelector('.forms')` where is `class="forms"`? Why is there a comma in the attributes? `placeholder="Write here",class="textbox"`

Comment: @epascarello, I changed it. It didn't work. But thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets explain futher what is happening when you create a node server such as yours.

When you start it (with `app.listen()`) the server will listen for incoming request and return an awnser.

If you try to access 'localhost:3000/dumb' the navigator request your server asking him for '/dumb' route. As it dosn't exist, the server awnser a 404 error.

If you now try to access 'localhost:3000/' the server find a route, execute your callback (`(req, res) => res.render('test')`) and in this callback you use Handlebar to generate an html page which is send to the navigator.

Then the navigator get the HTML, parse it and find several links (like `<script src="./test.js">` but also `<img href="./myimage.png">` or `<stylesheet href="./style.css">`)
To be able to fully render the page, the navigator will request each link it found to get the associated ressources.

So in your case the navigator send one more request to 'localhost:3000/test.js' and as in my first dumb example the server awnser that it doesn't know this route.

You could create a route for each ressource (`app.get('./test.js', /*...*/)` with a callback sending back the correct ressource.
But as those file are just static (doesn't need any computation), the most common way to solve it is to make them available staticly.
That means saying to your app "this folder is full of static file, juste serve them".

As i said you can just create a 'public' folder and tell your app it contains static files : `app.use(express.static('./public'));`
Of course './public' being a correct path from your root app (where package.json and node_modules is).

But then, every files and folders in this folder become a reachable route. So if you have a 'js' folder in it, and later you want to create an `app.get('/js', /*...*/)` route you will have a conflict.

So the common way is to serve this folder under a route. For example `app.use('/static', express.static('./public'));` will make everything under './public' folder available under '/static' routes. In your case 'localhost:3000/static/test.js'.

I hope this is more clear, sorry for the poor english, this is not my native language.

Comment: Oh man, that's a lot of information. Thank you so much for simplifying it so nicely. I am thankful.

Comment: Where did you learn these stuff man? I really want to learn with this kind of depth.

Comment: Ahah, I did 5 year of ingenior school and learned basic of lot of fields. This is just xp, keep learning and try to understand the more you can what is happening and you will get it.

Comment: 5 years wow, that's amazing. I want to make you my mentor. Lol

Comment: @DarkDevil I would be ok for that if you want, but i dont know how to contact you and i don't want to expose my public mail ...

Comment: Haha, thanks man. You are great, I was just joking. I will figure it out on my own. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 1):

Once your html is going back to your navigator, it will load any ressources it needs (such as images, css or script). This is why you got a 404 error, it can't reach 'localhost/test.js'

So you have to put test.js available.

The common way is yo use a /public folder and put every static ressources in it.

So where you have your node.js file, create a "public" folder

Put in it your test.js file.

Add this in Node before your app.listen() :

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

In HTML :

```
<script src="/static/test.js"></script>
```

'static' is the name you want for the public route
'public' is the name of the folder in your app

Of course you can change route and folder name as you wish.

And you can add subfolder to it. For example put test.js in path app/public/js/test.js.
And refer to it in HTML with src="/static/js/test.js"

Comment: thanks friend for helping me out. Are you suggesting me to create a directory called 'Static' where the main 'app.js' is located and put my files inside it?

Comment: Not exactly i edit my awnser so it will be more clear

Comment: Can you please elaborate this 'The common way is to use a /public folder and put every resource  available in it '

Comment: Should be more clear know, i stay available if you still need precision ;-)

Comment: Thank you a lot for simplifying it so nicely. I created a public directory under the src directory where my node.js file is located and  wrote this  'app.use('/static', express.static('public'));' before the app.listen and also <script src="/static/test.js"></script> on my test.hbs file but still the result is same. It's saying 'GET http://localhost:3000/static/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: Try putting the public directory on your root path not in the src folder (where node_modules and package.json is). Or pass express.static('./src/public').

Comment: Also i checked one of my projects, i was only using `app.use(express.static('public'));` with the public folder on the root of my directory (where package.json is).
And in html i refer to it with `src="./test.js"`

Comment: Oh! Before you posted the comment  21 minutes ago I figured it out and I did the way I did before but modified your code a little bit and it's working now. Inside the app.js, I wrote this 'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));' and in the <script src="/js/test.js"></script> in the test.hbs file.. My file structure now  looks like this https://ibb.co/W06F7RY

Comment: Yeah you got it, it is only a path issue.
But be carfule that any folder or file in your public directory will know be a route of your app.
In your case if you want to create a route '/js' it will be a conflict. That's why i talked about the `app.use('/static', express.static('/public'))` solution, so every static file is under the route '/static' ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much man, Really appreciate your help. You really did a lot and can you please give an upvote to my question? And btw, can you explain this, 'Once your html is going back to your navigator, it will load any resources it needs'

Comment: Np man ;-)
Sure i can explain more, but in those little section comment it is pretty hard to have great message. I will post one more awnser to you post to explain it futher

Comment: Please do that.